# Custom File Field Filename Error

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have created some custom file fields so I can add some files (pdf, doc, zip etc) to each user profile.

When I upload the files, everything works great.
I the backend the file names are displayed correclty, 
BUT in the frontent the filenames are changed:
a string like "_8b9c34bb85a1219b9e1f60e02d82907c" is atteched.

How can I fix this?
I use civicrm 4.6.11 and wordpress 3.8

**UPDATE 5/4/2016:**
I have tested version 4.6.14 and 4.7.4 on wordpress 4.4.2 (latest version)
on different *Plesk* (TopHost) and *Cpanel* (SiteGround) shared servers.

**The problem remain the same.**

The files are stored correctly but at the frontend an HTML text on the link is added.

See Screenshots:

[image: user profile custom fields backend]
user profile custom fields backend

[image: user profile custom fields frontend]
user profile custom fields frontend

[image: backend civicrm 4.6.14]
backend civicrm 4.6.14

[image: frontend profile page civicrm 4.6.14]
wordpress 4.4.2 frontend profile page civicrm 4.6.14

[image: server settings]
server settings

Comment: I have updated, CiviCRM to 4.7.4 and php to 5.5 but the promlem remains. When I upload a file, the string like "_c48647e27e457b3bb7237a9597d6852f" is attached to the name. Any workarounds? maybe it its a mysql problem?

Comment: I always assumed this was on purpose, that on the front-end civi added characters to uploaded files as part of a security measure. If you want to reference the file, you can use the API or token/variables.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have selected the correct datatype while creating the custom field value  - it should look like below

[image]

Comment: The properties are exactly as the screenshot that you posted, so no, this does not solves the problem. Any other hints?

Comment: hi I managed to test the same against Civicrm 4.6.11 version and wordpress 4.4.2 - which worked perfectly. So please try to upgrade the civicrm version and give a try. please don't upgrade to civicrm version 4.7 where we have some issue in custom field so its better to test with v4.6.11

Comment: I am already using v4.6.11, but an older version of wordpress. (3.8) I cannot upgrade wordpress because My theme does not support a greater version. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: If that is the case you need to try fixing your theme

Comment: Hello, I have updated, CiviCRM to 4.7.4 and php to 5.5 but the promlem remains. When I upload a file, the string like "_c48647e27e457b3bb7237a9597d6852f" is attached to the name. Any workarounds? maybe it its a mysql problem?

Comment: sorry @Qara their is a problem in custom field value updating File type in the latest version of Civicrm. So, Please with the same version CiviCRM 4.6.11  - Is their anyway you can test this issue with Civicrm 4.6.11

Comment: I have just installed a fresh wordpress 4.4.2 and civicrm 4.6.14 but the prosblem still remains. So it is not a wordpress or a civcrm version problem. Maybe it is a mysql settings problem or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to test the same against Civicrm 4.6.14 and custom field of type file is not working as excepted but still the file is been saved against the field but the display is incorrect

this is how it looks - in the display

[image]

if you try to edit the custom file is been displayed as below

[image]

So please check your installation - and then try again - thanks

Comment: Yes. on the backend of civicrm the filename is correct. But on the frontend (eg. the profile page of the user) the filename is damaged. see screenshots here: wordpress  backend http://i.imgur.com/RiIfMGy.png  frontend: http://i.imgur.com/CeSqHbz.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem you're describing is [CRM-18183](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18183).  Try upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.5+.